# Use a calculation inside the where part

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a problem formulating a sql query. The code is used in a php script accessing a sqlite database.

What I want to do: I only want to select datasets which are over an individual offset:

```
select * from tab1 t, tab2 z where t.id = z.ref and (t.value - z.offset > '50')
```

Why doesn't this work?

I tried another way but this fails too.

```
select *, t.value - z.offset as diff from tab1 t, tab2 z where t.id = z.ref and ( diff > '50')
```

The colum diff contains the correct value, but I cannot use it in the where clause.

Any idea how to formulate this?
Thanks for your help!
Galeo

Comment: What are **data types** for `t.value` and `z.offset`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `t.value` and `z.offset` are both of some *numeric* type, then re-write your last condition as `(t.value - z.offset > 50)` (no apostrophes).

Your `2nd` query uses **column alias** in `WHERE` clause which is not allowed.